# Changing the test directory in a Clojure/Leiningen project

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen

I created a new Clojurescript/Om project. The directory structure looks like this:

```
├── project.clj
├── resources
│   └── public
│       ├── index.html
│       └── src
│           └── om_tutorial
│               └── core.cljs
├── script
│   └── figwheel.clj
├── src
│   ├── clj
│   │   ├── test
│   │   └── example-project
│   │       └── core.clj
│   └── cljs
│       └── example-project
│           └── core.cljs
├── target
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── META-INF
│   │       └── maven
│   │           └── typing
│   │               └── typing
│   │                   └── pom.properties
│   └── stale
│       └── leiningen.core.classpath.extract-native-dependencies
└── test
    └── clj
        └── example-project
            └── test_core.clj
```

My `package.json` is very minimal, and it looks like this:

```
(defproject typing "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "example-project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.170"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-alpha22"]
                 [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.0-SNAPSHOT" :scope "test"]
                 [http-kit "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [compojure "1.5.0"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [cheshire "5.5.0"]]
  :test-paths ["test"])
```

However, I can't get Leiningen to recognize the test path. When I run `lein test`, I see:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate test/typing/test_core__init.class or test/example-project/test_core.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name., compiling:(/private/var/folders/dk/jvt798yj6ds6wnkwk_24wrcm0000gp/T/form-init5157365051258208935.clj:1:125)
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate test/example-project/test_core__init.class or test/example-project/test_core.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.
...
Tests failed.
```

I moved the tests from `test/clj/example-project/...` to `test/example-project/...`, and the implementation from `src/clj/example-project/` to `src/example-project` but I still see the same error.

How do I get Leiningen to recognize my tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the `:test-paths` need to reach in further so that source code can be found by lein.

You could try:

```
:test-paths ["test/clj"]
```

I see you moved source code around using basically the same thinking. But this is easier. Also after any changes to `project.clj` you need to `lein clean` then `lein deps`. My way is more about the `deps` and yours more about the `clean`, but both regardless is expedient. Also you need to check that `clean` is actually getting rid of output. If it is not you can always manually clean by deleting files.